# Get value Inside Observable in a nested Array of objects

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I consume an Api.

I get well data but I'm completely  lost to display informations.

I made a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w3qksu?) to explain the problem.

I just want to access to 'records' => 'fields' => 'name' values of each 'records'.

```json
{
    "nhits": 38,
    "parameters": {
        "dataset": "communes-de-la-province-de-namur",
        "rows": 1,
        "start": 0,
        "format": "json",
        "timezone": "UTC"
    },
    "records": [
        {
            "datasetid": "communes-de-la-province-de-namur",
            "recordid": "5f50799324d15038c9708e48c6a32c907922d00a",
            "fields": {
                "nsi": "93088",
                "geo_shape": {
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            [
                                4.516330595797285,
                                50.315159737224334
                            ],
                            [
                                4.516580864937829,
                                50.31404658899336
                            ],
                            [
                                4.516687125130969,
                                50.313425631678086
                            ],
                            [
                                4.516773208694129,
                                50.312758726847896
                            ],
                            [
                                4.51683388309065,
                                50.31199699971867
                            ],
                            [
                                4.511136348481946,
                                50.28826153347796
                            ],
                            [
                                4.5113662847970755,
                                50.28794282863673
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    "type": "Polygon"
                },
                "geo_point_2d": [
                    50.26709679846407,
                    4.433557385138468
                ],
                "name": "Walcourt"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    4.433557385138468,
                    50.26709679846407
                ]
            },
            "record_timestamp": "2019-02-13T15:00:55.334000+00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm very new to Angular, so any suggestions is helpfull.

Thank you!

Comment: Hello please don't put code or `json`  as picture. instead, copy it inside your question and wrap it inside triple backquotes: Example: `\`\`\`json`  your code `\`\`\``

Comment: @vinalti I tryed to past code but json file is to long even with only one record. More characters than allowed.

Comment: Can't you trim the part you need ? it seems to fit on your picture

Comment: It's done. Hope it can help. I removed some informations. This example is only for one record.

Comment: The quotes should be one line before and oneline after the code. Also please use a pretty print and remove the useless coordinates. Try to get something easy to understand and representing the data. ;)

Comment: Sorry. I reduced data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you in you HTML you have to change it like this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let record of (communes$ | async).records">
  {{  record.fields?.name  }}
</div>
```

and there is a problem with your observable type, this is correct: `public communes$: Observable<any>;`

because the response is an object and not an array of objects

Comment: It's seems to be better in Stackblitz project but when I do the same in my VS Code projet I have  an error : 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'records')'

Comment: this is probably because  `(communes$ | async)` is null at the  beginning.
probably you can fix it with `(communes$ | async)?.records` or with a `*ngIf=""`

Comment: Perfect it works. How can I sort the result?

Comment: you can create a custom sort pipe or you should subscribe to `communes$` in `ngOnInit` and sort it there.
Pleas consider to accept the answer above and ask another question on stackoverflow if you need more help